# how can i remove some namespaces from output

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have and XML with more namespaces. in output XML i need some of them and some of required.

XML INPUT:

```
    <root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ali="http://www.niso.org/schemas/ali/1.0"
    xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <child1>child1</child1>
    <child2>child2</child2>
    <child3>child3</child3>
    <child4>child4</child4>
</root>
```

XSLT :

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ali="http://www.niso.org/schemas/ali/1.0"
    xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    extension-element-prefixes="ali"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs ali xsi mml xlink"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

MY OUTPUT:

```
    <root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ali="http://www.niso.org/schemas/ali/1.0" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <child1>child1</child1>
    <child2>child2</child2>
    <child3>child3</child3>
    <child4>child4</child4>
</root>
```

MY REQUIRED OUTPUT:

Need removed these only two namespaces ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::* except namespace::ali"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: after using this it is removing all namespaces and coming with 'ali' one. My requirement is dropping 'ali' only others should be come.

Comment: add all namespace you want in xsl:namespace, and delete ali

Comment: Thank you! @Rupesh!! This is working well but here to removing only one namespace we are stopping all namespaces and again we applying all excepting one. If any logic to removing only one!!! But anyway now i solve my problem thanks again! :)

Comment: To copy all namespaces except one you can write `<xsl:copy select="namespace::* except namespace::ali"/>`

Comment: Sir, @MichaelKay thanks for your reply. But here is some problem: 1. select attribute is allow in 3.0? 2. after changing the version its not process. can you please give me the example code if posible?

Comment: Thanks, i got it now.